# How to raise django validation error on login form (which is on a bootstrap modal on index.html)?

Tags: python, django

```
#below is login view
def login_view(request):
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())
        next = request.GET.get('next')
        title = "Login"
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():    
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)        
            if next:
                return redirect(next)
            return redirect("/userdashboard")
        return render(request, "index.html", {"form":form, "title": title})
```

## how can i return error message on login form (which is in bootstrap modal)

Comment: Try using the `clean()` method in your `UserLoginForm()` to raise exceptions if the values are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the bootstrap modal use form errors in loop.

```py
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this code is working but the bootstrap modal is not automatically opening after false submission

Comment: Automatically means? The modal needs to be opened ny clicking on a button or so

Comment: Thanks for your efforts
pls follow these steps
1. After clicking login tab : a modal will appear with login form
2.Enter username and password
3.Error should be raised on current opened login modal (if validation fails)
is this fine, did you get my problem statement ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Http404` condition  to render error message on login. Import `Http404` the class is **django.http.Http404** if you raise any error in that case Django will return the error message or page that you set to be displayed ex: 404.html. You code may look like this:

```
def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    try:
        if form.is_valid():    
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)        
            if next:
                return redirect(next)
            return redirect("/userdashboard")
    except:
        raise Http404 (" This user does not exist.")
    return render(request, "index.html", {"form":form, "title": title})
```

Comment: Raising validation error is fine, but how to display the error message on form, where this form is located on Bootstrap Modal in index.html